# how to create a single method in repository pattern to get all data but works for all the class in dbSet

Tags: .net, linq, repository-pattern

im very confused in the repository pattern ,the reason where ever I seen this pattern on the internet there is no method to Select ALL() without specifying any filter,because for example imagine I have table name is Students,i want to select all student names,and also I need to select all books from Books table,for each of them in generic repository I should write specific Select all method?

**Here is my Repository**

```
public class GenericRepositoryTest<TEntity> where TEntity:class
{

    internal CentralEntities context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;


    public GenericRepositoryTest(CentralEntities context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }


    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get( Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);


        }



        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is my UNitOfWork**

```
    private CentralEntities context = new CentralEntities();
   private GenericRepositoryTest<Books> usrRepo;
   private GenericRepositoryTest<Students> mastrData;



   public IEnumerable<Students> getAllStudentsOfData()
   {

       return context.Students.ToList();

   }


  public IEnumerable<Books> getAllOfBookData()
   {

       return context.Books.ToList();

   }
```

so if for every single table like above, I should create something the same ?
is there any generic method to do the same for all tables?

Comment: You might be interested in this article: https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want. You can certainly have only *one* generic repository: just remove the generic and constraint from your Repository class and move the constraint to each method. You will also need to move the second line of your constructor there. That means you can use a different type with every method call, so one single repository can handle all calls you may want to make.

If you *want* that is up to you. You can find a full implementation of this [here](https://cpratt.co/truly-generic-repository/).

As for the "SelectAll" method, I don't really know wat you mean. Just call your `Get` method *without* any filter, like `genericRepository.Get();` or `genericRepository.Get<Student>();` if you implement the suggestion above. You will get all.

Comment: thanks for your comment,my problem is I have no idea when I want to do a join between two tables in my controller,using the above repository what should I do?normally in a join,i need to do for example ( select s from students JOIN t in Books where t.id==s.id)   ,right?but with the above repository I cant do that ,I get error